# Bash while loop `done' syntax error unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop, virtualbox

Learning bash scripting in Linux on VirtualBox.

I'm writing a script that uses a while loop to ask what text file to write to if you decide not to overwrite an existing file, among other things.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

bool="true"
counter="true"
while [ "${bool}" == "true" ] ; do
    bool="false"
    if [ "${counter}" == "true" ] ; then
    if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
        ff=$1
    fi
    else
    read -p "Enter the .txt file you would like to write to: " ff
    fi

    txt=".txt"
    if [[ $ff != *$txt* ]] ; then
    echo $ff
    ff="$ff$txt"
    echo $ff
    fi

    if [ -w $ff ] ; then
    var="true"
    while [ "${var}" == "true" ] ; do
        var="false"
        read -p "${ff} already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? y/n: " yorn
        if [ $yorn == "y" ] ; then
        echo "'$ff' is being overwitten"
        elif [ $yorn == "n" ] ; then
        echo "Let's try this again..."
        bool="true"     
        else
        echo "You entered a command other than y or n."
        var="true"
        fi
    done
    else
    echo "'$ff' has been created"
    fi

    counter="false"
done

echo "Writing to ${ff}..."
echo "${ff}" > $ff
echo "" >> $ff

declare -a alphabet=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z")
echo ${alphabet[@]}
letters=${#alphabet[@]}
echo "There are ${letters} letters in the alphabet"
loops=$((letters*letters*letters))
echo "The script loops ${loops} times"

start=$(date +%s.%N)
for x in "${alphabet[@]}"
do
    x=$x$x
    for y in "${alphabet[@]}"
    do
    y=$y$y
    for z in "${alphabet[@]}"
    do
        z=$z$z
        xyz=$x$y$z
        grep $xyz /usr/share/dict/words >> $ff
    done
    done
done
end=$(date +%s.%N)
elapsed=$(echo "$end - $start" | bc -l)
echo "The search took ${elapsed} seconds."

sleep 10s
emacs $ff

exit 0
```

Here's my error for the done of the while loop:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/scripts$ ./script.sh abc
./script.sh: line 35: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./script.sh: line 35: `done'
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: is your indentation like this in your real file? There are several blocks that would be easier to read if they were indented.

Comment: you are missing a **fi** after echo "'$ff' has been created" fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1) You need a space here. As a general suggestion, it's better to use shell built-in`[[ ... ]]` over the test `[ ... ]` in bash.

```
if [ "${counter}" == "true" ] ; then
                           ^
```

2) You are not closing the if with "fi" here.

```
  elif [ $yorn == "n" ] ; then
        echo "Let's try this again..."
        bool=true
  fi # <--- Closing "fi" here
```

If you indent your code, you could easily spot these kind of errors more quickly.